# Converting C# application from sharepoint 2007 to 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

So I am not a programmer, I'm a systems admin.  I've been asked to try and convert an application that someone (no longer with us) developed for our SharePoint 2007 environment to the new SharePoint 2013 environment.  Does anyone have any suggestions regarding how to approach this?  Thus far I have tried to build a new application via VS 2012 but my general ignorance surrounding this type of migration has led to issues around not knowing what is part of the old environment and what is part of the code in the aspx and dll files.  Any advise on a more automated approach would be much appreciated and do let me know if I should provide more information.

Comment: We're not going to be able to help you much without more detail on the application. My thought is: if the application is important, then hire a developer to convert it (assuming that it doesn't "just work").

Comment: SharePoint is nothing to just fiddle with.

Answer (score 2):

Hire a developer with good working knowledge of both SharePoint versions.

You will possibly run into countless issues, small and big, and being a sysadmin you won't have the knowledge to identify them properly and fix them. Further, you will have to solve data migration.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your case. However if your application is some "*.wsp" file there is chance that ir will work on SP 2013 without any changes.

Comment: I have all of the installed files (dll, webart, Usercontrols and data) for the old environment but I do not have the VS project files.  I've tried exporting and importing the webpart.  It does it but it throws a something went wrong error when I try to view the page that I add the webpart to.  I have to close or delete the webpart through the webpart management page.